# Pythonic way and time saving to remove empty element nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried different way to remove empty element to nested list, but I don't know if the best way on 100k list.

Example:

```
tag = [['A', 'B', 'C', ''], ['D', 'F', 'G', '', '',''], ['H','I','J'],['L','M','','','','']]
```

I find different approaches like:

```
list(filter(None, tag))
```

or

```
for i in tag:
    test_list = [i for i in tag if i]
```

or

```
'' in [j for i in tag for j in i]
```

No way, I cannot remove empty element, first, and second, time to achieve it, is too slow. 
Also I tried to develop few nested list on python tutor, but don't remove anything.

Suggestion please?
thank you

Comment: Please, post [mcve].

Comment: I bet this has been asked a million times before => bingo

Comment: Yes sure, million times, but not the performance. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if performance would satisfy, but

```
tags = [['A', 'B', 'C', ''], ['D', 'F', 'G', '', '',''],
        ['H','I','J'],['L','M','','','','']]
filtered_tags = [[tag for tag in item if tag] for item in tags]
print(filtered_tags)
```

output

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'F', 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['L', 'M']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` with list comprehension.

```
[list(filter(None,l)) for l in tag]
# [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'F', 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['L', 'M']]
```

Or

```
[[i for i in l if i] for l in tag]
# [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'F', 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['L', 'M']]
```

Some *timeit* analysis using Python 3.7 windows 10.

```
#Using list of size 100_000 i.e len(tag)=100_000 for benchmarking
In [12]: timeit [list(filter(None,l)) for l in tag]
42.1 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [13]: timeit [[i for i in l if i] for l in tag]
34.7 ms ± 733 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```